# Loading and manipulating bitmaps in C

Tags: c, bitmap

I have the two files below which I am required to use. `bmplib.h`...

```
#ifndef BMPLIB_H
#define BMPLIB_H

typedef struct {
  unsigned short padding;
  unsigned short bfType;
  unsigned int bfSize;
  unsigned short bfReserved1;
  unsigned short bfReserved2;
  unsigned int bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct {
  unsigned int biSize;
  int biWidth;
  int biHeight;
  unsigned short biPlanes;
  unsigned short biBitCount;
  unsigned int biCompression;
  unsigned int biSizeImage;
  unsigned int biXPelsPerMeter;
  unsigned int biYPelsPerMeter;
  unsigned int biClrUsed;
  unsigned int biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;

typedef struct {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
} PIXEL;

#define DEFAULT_BITMAP_OFFSET 1078

/* Read an uncompressed 24-bit bmp from a file named 'filename' (if
   null, it's standard input); return the number of 'rows', the number
   of 'cols', and the 'bitmap' as an array of PIXELs. The function
   return 0 if successful. */
int readFile (char* filename, int* rows, int* cols, PIXEL** bitmap);


/* Write an uncompressed 24-bit bmp to a file named 'filename' (if
   null, it's standard output); the dimension of the bmp is the number
   of 'rows' by the number of 'cols', and the 'bitmap' contains an
   array of PIXELs.  The function return 0 if successful. */
int writeFile (char* filename, int rows, int cols, PIXEL* bitmap);

/* Read bmp file header from file 'fd', return the number of 'rows',
   the number of 'cols', and the 'start' position of the bitmap. The
   function returns 0 if successful. */
int readHeader(int fd, int *rows, int *cols, unsigned int *start);

/* Write bmp file header to file 'fd'; the dimention of the bitmap is
   the number of 'rows' by the number of 'cols', and it starts at the
   'start' position. The function returns 0 if successful. */
int writeHeader(int fd, int rows, int cols, unsigned int start);

/* Read the 'bitmap' from file 'fd'; the dimention of the bitmap is
   the number of 'rows' by the number of 'cols', and it starts at the
   'start' position. The function returns 0 if successful. */
int readBits(int fd, PIXEL* bitmap, int rows, int cols, unsigned int start);

/* Write the 'bitmap' to file 'fd'; the dimention of the bitmap is the
   number of 'rows' by the number of 'cols', and it starts at the
   'start' position. The function returns 0 if successful. */
int writeBits(int fd, int rows, int cols, PIXEL* bitmap, unsigned int start);

#endif /*BMPLIB_H*/
```

and `bmplib.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "bmplib.h"

static int myread(int fd, char* buf, unsigned int size)
{
  int r = 0;
  while(r < size) {
    int x = read(fd, &buf[r], size-r);
    if(x < 0) return x;
    else r += x;
  }
  return size;
}

static int mywrite(int fd, char* buf, unsigned int size)
{
  int w = 0;
  while(w < size) {
    int x = write(fd, &buf[w], size-w);
    if(x < 0) return x;
    else w += x;
  }
  return size;
}

int readFile (char *filename, int *rows, int *cols, PIXEL** bitmap) 
{
  int fd, ret;
  unsigned int start;

  if(filename) {
    if((fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
      perror("Can't open bmp file to read");
      return -1;
    }
  } else fd = STDIN_FILENO;

  ret = readHeader (fd, rows, cols, &start);
  if(ret) return ret;

  *bitmap = (PIXEL*)malloc(sizeof(PIXEL)*(*rows)*(*cols));
  ret = readBits (fd, *bitmap, *rows, *cols, start);
  if(ret) return ret;

  if(filename) close(fd);

  return 0;
}

int writeFile (char* filename, int rows, int cols, PIXEL* bitmap) 
{
  int fd, ret;
  unsigned int start = DEFAULT_BITMAP_OFFSET;

  if(filename) {
    if((fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)) < 0) {
      perror("Can't open bmp file to write");
      return -1;
    }
  } else fd = STDOUT_FILENO;

  ret = writeHeader (fd, rows, cols, start);
  if(ret) return ret;

  ret = writeBits(fd, rows, cols, bitmap, start);
  if(ret) return ret;

  if(filename) close(fd);

  return 0;
}

int readHeader(int fd, int *rows, int *cols, unsigned int *start) 
{
  BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;

  if(myread(fd, ((char*)&bmfh)+2, sizeof(bmfh)-2) <= 0) {
    perror("Can't read BITMAPFILEHEADER");
    return -2;
  }
  if(myread(fd, (char*)&bmih, sizeof(bmih)) <= 0) {
    perror("Can't read BITMAPINFOHEADER");
    return -3;
  }

  if(bmih.biCompression != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't read compressed bmp");
    return -4;
  }
  if(bmih.biBitCount != 24) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't handle bmp other than 24-bit");
    return -5;
  }

  *rows = bmih.biHeight;
  *cols = bmih.biWidth;
  *start = bmfh.bfOffBits;

  return 0;
}

int writeHeader(int fd, int rows, int cols, unsigned int start)
{
  unsigned int fileSize;
  unsigned int headerSize;
  unsigned int paddedCols;
  BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
  BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;

  memset (&bmfh, 0, sizeof(bmfh));
  memset (&bmih, 0, sizeof(bmih));

  paddedCols = ((cols/4)*4 !=cols ? ((cols+4)/4)*4 : cols);
  headerSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  fileSize = rows*paddedCols*sizeof(PIXEL)+headerSize;

  bmfh.bfType = 0x4D42;
  bmfh.bfSize = fileSize;
  bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
  bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
  bmfh.bfOffBits = start;

  bmih.biSize = 40;
  bmih.biWidth  = cols;
  bmih.biHeight = rows;
  bmih.biPlanes = 1;
  bmih.biBitCount = 24;
  bmih.biCompression = 0;
  bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
  bmih.biXPelsPerMeter  = 0;
  bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
  bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
  bmih.biClrImportant = 0;

  if(mywrite(fd, ((char*)&bmfh)+2, sizeof(bmfh)-2) < 0) {
    perror("Can't write BITMAPFILEHEADER");
    return -2;
  }
  if(mywrite(fd, (char*)&bmih, sizeof(bmih)) < 0) {
    perror("Can't write BITMAPINFOHEADER");
    return -3;
  }

  return 0;
}

int readBits(int fd, PIXEL* bitmap, int rows, int cols, unsigned int start) 
{
  int row;
  char padding[3];
  int padAmount;
  char useless[DEFAULT_BITMAP_OFFSET];

  padAmount = ((cols * sizeof(PIXEL)) % 4) ? (4 - ((cols * sizeof(PIXEL)) % 4)) : 0;

  start -= sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)-2+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  if(start > 0 && myread(fd, useless, start) < 0) { 
    perror("Can't lseek to bitmap");
    return -6;
  }
  /*
  if(lseek (fd, start, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
    perror("Can't lseek to bitmap");
    return -6;
  }
  */

  for (row=0; row < rows; row++) {
    if(myread(fd, (char*)(bitmap+(row*cols)), cols*sizeof(PIXEL)) < 0) {
      perror("Can't read bitmap");
      return -7;
    }
    if(padAmount > 0) { 
      if(myread(fd, padding, padAmount) < 0) {
    perror("Can't read bitmap");
    return -8;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int writeBits(int fd, int rows, int cols, PIXEL* bitmap, unsigned int start) 
{
  int row;
  char padding[3];
  int padAmount;
  char useless[DEFAULT_BITMAP_OFFSET];

  padAmount = ((cols * sizeof(PIXEL)) % 4) ? (4 - ((cols * sizeof(PIXEL)) % 4)) : 0;
  memset(padding, 0, 3);

  start -= sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)-2+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  if(start > 0) {
    memset(useless, 0, start);
    if(mywrite(fd, useless, start) < 0) { 
      perror("Can't lseek to bitmap");
      return -6;
    }
  }
  /*
  if(lseek (fd, start, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
    perror("Can't lseek to bitmap");
    return -6;
  }
  */

  for (row=0; row < rows; row++) {
    if(mywrite(fd, (char*)(bitmap+(row*cols)), cols*sizeof(PIXEL)) < 0) {
      perror("Can't write bitmap");
      return -7;
    }
    if(padAmount > 0) { 
      if(mywrite(fd, padding, padAmount) < 0) {
    perror("Can't write bitmap");
    return -8;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying  to understand how I can load a bitmap image using the `readInput` function, but I am utterly confused as to what parameters I need to pass for rows, columns, and the PIXEL array. Furthermore I don't quite understand how it is I can use this library to manipulate a bitmap; to enlarge it or flip it 90 degrees. Can someone please explain how this code works, **particularly how can I use the functions below to successfully load a bitmap image, and either enlarge it or flip it.**

Comment: This is only an input/output library. It only defines functions to read or write bitmaps, not perform operations in memory. You'll either have to find a library that supports those functions, or write them yourself.

Comment: @owacoder Makes sense. But I still need help making sense of the `readInput` function and its parameters.

Comment: The comments in the header explain what each function does and how to use it. The readxxx functions "return" multiple values by their arguments, and the writexxx functions write data based on their arguments' values. If you're still confused you might want to pick up a good C book.

Comment: @owacoder I understand that, but what values do I pass to the function, given a bitmap file? I know the file name, but how can I know how many rows or columns the image has? I can't simply pass arbitrary values to `readInput` can I?

Comment: You should reread the comment for the `readFile` function. You should pass the filename, and *addresses* to variables where the number of rows, columns, etc. should be stored. You don't need to initialize these other variables. The values are used as return values, although not technically returned from the function, just set by it. Please, pick up a C book and learn the many different conventions people use for passing data to and getting data from functions.